# Warum wird "weil" zur nebenordnenden Konjunktion?

Tags: sentence-structure, conjunction

Gibt es wissenschaftliche Untersuchungen darüber, warum die Konjunktion *weil* derzeit einen Sprachwandel erlebt? Mein Eindruck ist, dass die anderen Konjunktionen vergleichsweise statisch sind.

Offenbar wandelt sich *weil* von einer Konjunktion zwischen Hauptsatz und Nebensatz zu einer Konjunktion zwischen Hauptsätzen. Mich interessiert, ob dieses Phänomen hinsichtlich seines zeitlichen Aufkommens und seiner sprachlichen Ursachen untersucht worden ist.

Meine Vermutung im Bezug auf die Motivation ist, dass kausale Beziehungen eine erhöhte Denkleistung beanspruchen, so dass die Satzstellung SOV durch die für den deutschen Sprecher natürlichere Satzstellung SVO ersetzt worden ist. Insbesondere bei Konstruktionen mit Hilfsverben ist dies naheliegend.

> „Warum ist so wenig Salz in der Suppe“ – „Weil du kannst doch nicht zu viel Salz essen, das ist ungesund.“
>
> „Ich habe die Hausaufgaben nicht gemacht, weil ich musste meinen Hund wegen Magenschmerzen ins Krankenhaus fahren.“

Würde man im ersten Beispiel die Antwort in SOV formulieren, dann würde man noch nicht einmal mit einem richtigen Satz antworten, sondern nur mit einem Adverb. Ebenfalls vermutlich eine Motivation.

Comment: Ich habe keine Quelle für eine Untersuchung aber dieser Wandel wurde in 2 oder 3 Büchern, die sich allgemein mit der Deutschen Sprache beschäftigt haben und teils von Linguisten geschrieben wurden (den Jahren 2009 bis 2012) erwähnt. Die Wissenschaft dürfte das also auf dem Schirm haben :)

Comment: Zum ersten Mal bewusst geworden ist mir diese Satzstellung bei Familie Feuerstein. Ich glaube, Fred hat immer lange Ketten von Begründungen mit "weil" verbunden. Etwa so: "Ich habe Hunger. Weil: Es gab nichts zum Mittagessen. Weil: Wilma hat nicht gekocht. Weil: Sie ist böse auf mich. Weil: Ich war gestern zu lange bei Barney." (Natürlich alles rein fiktiv, nur um das Prinzip zu zeigen.) Im Übrigen würde ich "Weil"+Hauptsatz auch so verschriftlichen: Mit einem Doppelpunkt nach "weil".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Üblicherweise und im geschriebenen Standarddeutsch werden nebengeordnete Haupt- oder Nebensätze mit folgenden [Konjunktionen](http://www.canoonet.eu//services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Konjunktion/Gebrauch/koord.html) gebildet:

> *aber, allein, außer, beziehungsweise, denn, doch, jedoch, oder, sondern, sowie, und und wie.*

Die Konjunktion weil gehört zu den [unterordnenden Konjunktionen](http://www.canoonet.eu//services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Konjunktion/Gebrauch/subord.html).

Bei untergeordneten Nebensätzen rückt das Verb an das Ende des Nebensatzes:

> Mein Computer ist langsam, weil er schon alt ist.

Nebengeordnete Hauptsätze erkennt man an der [Verbzweitstellung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/V2-Stellung) (V2-Stellung) wie im folgenden Satz:

> Mein Computer ist langsam, denn er ist schon alt.

Im gesprochenen Deutsch findet man aber zunehmend auch *"weil"* in der Funktion einer nebenordnenden Konjunktion, die aus obigem Beispiel den folgenden Ausspruch bildet:

> *"Mein Computer ist langsam, weil er ist schon alt."*

Diese grammatikalische Funktion wurde in der Vergangenheit kritisiert (z. B. [Bastian Sick - Zwiebelfisch 2005](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-weil-das-ist-ein-nebensatz-a-350013.html)), aber es ist tatsächlich so, dass die Verwendung von *"weil"* mit Verbzweitstellung mittlerweile so gebräuchlich ist, dass sie schon längst Einzug in den [Duden](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/satzbau-nach-weil) gefunden hat. Allerdings wird dort noch darauf hingewiesen, dass sie der gesprochenen Sprache vorbehalten sei, da standardsprachlich nicht korrekt.

Es gibt eine ganze Reihe sprachwissenschaftlicher Untersuchungen über die Verbzweitstellung nach weil. Häufig werden hier die Arbeiten von [Schwitalla](http://www.germanistik.uni-wuerzburg.de/lehrstuehle/lehrstuhl_fuer_deutsche_sprachwissenschaft/mitarbeiter/ehemalige/schwitalla/) genannt, der zeigen konnte, dass diese Konstruktion nicht nur in der gesprochenen Sprache, sondern auch in der Schriftsprache verkommt, und zwar auch dann, wenn es nicht nur um Zitate eines gesprochenen Wortes geht.

Sprachwissenschaftler und Linguisten beschreiben hier aber meist nur die Häufigkeit von sprachlichen Ausdrücken und geben allenfalls Vermutungen zu den Gründen ihrer Verwendung. [Weidacher](http://books.google.de/books?id=aCXnAAAAMAAJ) vermutet ein stilistisches Mittel, um einen trockenen Text aufzulockern. In der gesprochenen Sprache diene es als diskursordnendes Element ([Gansel 2007](http://books.google.de/books?id=jjIQpahU0RwC)).

Es ist also tatsächlich so, dass man einen Sprachwandel beobachten kann, der zur Verwendung von *"weil"* als nebenordnende Konjunktion führt. Man sollte sich aber dessen bewusst sein, dass es derzeit noch nicht weit verbreitet ist und unter Umständen auch als falsch angesehen wird.

***Weiterführende Literatur:***

- [M. Reif 2012: Verbzweitstellung nach "weil".: Ein syntaktisches Phänomen im gesprochenen Deutsch.](http://books.google.de/books?id=HelgYr2zIqoC)
- [K. Schwenke 2007: Eine Semantische Untersuchung Der Konjunktion 'Weil' Mit Verbletzt- Und Verbzweitstellung](http://books.google.de/books?id=_iYBSMpph18C)
- [A. Birk, C. Buffagni 2012: Linguistik und Sprachdidaktik im universitären DaF-Unterricht](http://books.google.de/books?id=or_ZYun65FoC)
- [J. Schwitalla 2006: Gesprochenes Deutsch: eine Einführung](http://books.google.de/books?id=aCXnAAAAMAAJ)
- [K.-M- Köpcke, A. Ziegler 2011: Grammatik – Lehren, Lernen, Verstehen: Zugänge zur Grammatik des Gegenwartsdeutschen](http://books.google.de/books?id=aCXnAAAAMAAJ)
- [C. Gansel, F. Jürgens 2007: Textlinguistik und Textgrammatik: eine Einführung](http://books.google.de/books?id=jjIQpahU0RwC)
- [A. Ziegler 2010: Historische Textgrammatik und Historische Syntax des Deutschen](http://books.google.de/books?id=p_rHgPUr9B4C)

Comment: Wow, ich würde für diese Antwort gerne +10 geben. Ich werd' mir mal ein paar Accounts machen :)... nebenbei bemerkt, Bastian Sick beklagt sich einfach über alle's und seine Comedy DVD ist nicht so gut. Das musste mal gesagt worden sein.

Comment: @Emanuel: Warum kein Bounty? Das geht auch mit einem Account.

Answer (score 5):

Die "weil-Hauptsatz-Konstruktion" ist weder falsch noch stammt sie aus dem Englischen noch ist ihre verbreitete Verwendung eine Entwicklung jüngeren Datums. Im Gegenteil waren Linguisten lange Zeit der Meinung, die Verb-*End*stellung sei aus dem Lateinischen übernommen! Auch dies ist allerdings nicht richtig, beide Formen, die Verb-End- und die Verb-Zweitstellung gibt es bereits im Mittelhochdeutschen, und beide Formen im Neben- ebenso wie im Hauptsatz.

Noch Luther schrieb (1545):

> Die weil du hast gehorchet der stimme deines Weibes / Vnd gessen von dem Bawm ... (3. Mose 7,19; "dieweil" ist die ursprüngliche Form von "weil")

In der *Deutschen Sprachgeschichte* schreibt Peter von Polenz (S. 190):

> Die Verb-Endstellung im Nebensatz ist erst im Laufe der frühnhd. Zeit zum grammatikalisierten Nebensatz-Kennzeichen geworden, zusammen mit der Ausbildung eines Systems von Subjunktionen für die Nebensatz-Einleitung und der allmählichen Festigung der Zweitstellung des Verbs als Hauptsatzkennzeichen.
>   Die zunehmend klare Unterscheidung in Hauptsatz und Nebensatz ist eine kontinuierliche Neuerung gegenüber dem Mittelhochdeutschen. Die Verb-Endstellung war im 15. Jh. noch leicht rückläufig (sic!), nahm dann aber ständig zu, bis zu ihrer bildungssprachlichen Absolutheit seit dem 17. Jh. Ostmitteldeutsche Texte waren darin fortschrittlicher als oberdeutsche.

Erst durch seine Verwendung im "Kanzlei-, Geschäfts- und Wissenschaftsstil" wird "die absolute oder hyperkorrekte Durchführung" des Satzrahmens – im Nebensatz gebildet aus Relativpronomen, Konkunktionen oder ähnlichem am Nebensatzanfang und finitem Verb am Nebensatzende: "weil ... ist." – "zum amtlichen bzw. gelehrten Prestigemuster" (ebd.).

Das Mittel**hoch**deutsche und seine Satzstellung findet seine sprachgeschichtliche Fortsetzung in den mittel- und oberdeutschen Dialekten, und in diesen (beispielsweise im Bairischen und Alemannischen) ist die Verbzweitstellung auch heute noch üblich und korrekt. Nur wo die schriftsprachliche Standardsprache die ausgestorbenen niederdeutschen Dialekte ersetzt hat (wie examplarisch in Hannover) ist die Verbzweitstellung im Nebensatz auch in der gesprochenen Sprache unüblich und wird als falsch empfunden.

Was wir heute beobachten ist also die Ausbreitung der gesprochenen Sprache und der Dialekte in standardschriftsprachliche Formen hinein, was sich wahrscheinlich vor allem der ubiquitären Verbreitung schriftsprachlicher Kommunikationsmedien wie Internet, SMS und Chat und damit der in jüngster Zeit auch schriftsprachlichen Kommunikation von nicht-akademischen Bevölkerungsgruppen verdankt, die sich bisher überwiegend mündlich ausgetauscht haben und deren Sprachverwendung gelehrten Schreibern deshalb vormals weniger aufgefallen ist und deren Schreib- und Sprechweisen auch nicht beeinflusst hat.

Answer (score 4):

Ich vermute, hier sieht man ein erstes Anzeichen dafür, dass die Verbstellung am Satzende als schwerfällig empfunden wird, zumindest beim umgangssprachlichen Sprechen. Beim Formulieren eines Gedankens geht das ja im Grunde so vor sich:

- Ich konnte nicht kommen. – Warum? – Ich war krank.

Aus solchen Sätzen entstanden meistens Satzgefüge mit untergeordneten Nebensätzen und um die Unterordnung des Nebensatzes kenntlich zu machen, hat sich die Verb-Endstellung durchgesetzt.

Man sieht die Entstehung von unterordnenden Konjunktionen in einigen Sprachen sehr deutlich. Im Italienischen heißt perché warum (eigentlich "für/durch was") und weil.

Im umgangssprachlichen Gesprächston hört man heute schon sehr oft die Konstruktion weil + Hauptsatzstellung, weil das eben leichter zu handhaben ist. Dieses Phänomen ist momentan aber nur bei "weil" zu beobachten. Vielleicht greift diese Erscheinung einmal um sich, damit käme Deutsch von seiner schwerfälligen Nebensatzstellung los.

Wie jemand schon richtig bemerkt hat (finde es leider nicht mehr), wird nach "weil" oft eine Sprechpause gemacht, weil man den Gedanken erst noch formulieren muss, und fährt dann nach der Pause einfach mit einem Hauptsatz fort. Im Grunde handelt es sich um einen Wechsel der Satzkonstruktion beim alltäglichen Reden, wie das eigentlich laufend der Fall ist. Wir reden im Alltag ja keine druckfertigen Texte.
Viele Sätze werden einfach abgebrochen und man fängt einen neuen Satz an.

Wenn man solche "gebrochene Sätze" in Texten schreibt, sollte man keinen Doppelpunkt wählen, sondern eher einen Gedankenstrich, der gleichzeitig die Sprechpause und den Wechsel der Satzkonstruktion andeuten könnte.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: Diese Antwort ist nicht wissenschaftlich belegt, falls jemand Studien dazu kennt (Analyse von Pausenzeiten, EEG, MRT o.ä.) lösche ich meine Antwort gern zugunsten einer besseren. Für einen Kommentar war sie aber zu lang.

Zitat OP:

> Meine Vermutung im Bezug auf die Motivation ist, dass kausale Beziehung eine erhöhte Denkleistung beanspruchen, so dass die Satzstellung SOV durch die für den deutschen Sprecher natürlichere Satzstellung SVO ersetzt worden ist. Insbesondere bei Konstruktion mit Hilfsverben ist dies naheliegend.

Gerade in der gesprochenen Sprache kann man auch mit einer Gedächtnisleitung argumentieren:

1. Konstruktion des Schlusses als Hauptsatz
2. Feststellung der Notwendigkeit einer Bedingung
3. **Kognitive Aktivität zum Finden der Bedingung**
4. Konstruktion der Bedingung als Nebensatz

Während (3) muss die Satzkonstruktion im Gedächtnis behalten werden. Wenn dieses Szenario stimmt, sollten die Zeiten für/Aktivitäten bei (3) mit der Häufigkeit von finiten Verben in Zweitstellung bei (4) zusammenpassen. Allerdings gibt es Confounder (Intelligenz, soziales Umfeld), die sich sowohl auf (3) als auch (4) separat auswirken sowie Übungseffekte (v.a., wenn die Versuchsperson die Letztstellung als Norm empfindet). Sollte also nicht ganz leicht sein, das zu untersuchen.

Comment: Neulich habe ich mich dabei ertappt, wie ich gegenüber einer Arzthelferin "weil" auf diese Weise verwendete. Hier kamen zwei Bedingungen zusammen: (1) die Ansprechpartnerin könnte sich durch korrektes Deutsch "von oben herab behandelt" fühlen und (2) mein Wunsch, eventuellen unangenehemen Konsequenzen einer solchen Wahrnehmung aus dem Weg zu gehen.

Answer (score 2):

Da @Takkat die Frage nach der Literatur schon soweit beantwortet hat, dass hier vielleicht auch andere Aspekte beleuchtet werden können, zunächst eine ganz simple Beobachtung: "weil" wird in der gesprochenen und der geschriebenen Alltagssprache mit der Satzstellung Subjekt — Verb — Objekt verwendet, weil es mit "denn" verwechselt oder, positiv ausgedrückt, gleichgesetzt wird:

> Ich erkannte ihn auf der Straße nicht, **weil** *er* einen breitkrempigen
>   Hut und eine riesige Sonnenbrille *trug*.
>
> Ich erkannte ihn auf der Straße nicht, **denn** *er trug* einen
>   breitkrempigen Hut und eine riesige Sonnenbrille.

"Weil", das heute eine Kausalbeziehung ausdrückt, hat ursprünglich auf eine zeitliche Relation hingewiesen. Es klingt nicht zufällig so ähnlich wie "Weile" (= ein gewisser, meist kurzer Zeitraum), ist eigentlich gleichbedeutend mit "so lange als", und  man kann auch mit "solange" einen Satz konstruieren, der sowohl von der Satzstellung als auch von der Aussage her der Formulierung mit "weil" ebenbürtig ist:

> Ich erkannte ihn auf der Straße nicht, **solange** *er* einen Hut und eine
>   Sonnenbrille *trug*.

Hier ist die Satzstellung eindeutig, denn auch umgangssprachlich funktioniert "solange" nur mit der SOV-Syntax.

Mit "denn" ist es komplizierter, es kommen nicht nur zeitliche Relationen vor, und die Satzstellungen sind unterschiedlich. "Denn" konnte für "als", "wenn nicht", "nämlich", "nachher", "dann", "aber" oder "ferner" stehen. Doch an erster Stelle steht die kausale Beziehung mit der Syntax "SVO":

> Ich erkannte ihn auf der Straße nicht, **denn** *er trug* einen Hut und eine
>   Sonnenbrille.
>
> Ich erkannte ihn auf der Straße nicht, *er trug* **nämlich** einen Hut und
>   eine Sonnenbrille.

In der Alltagssprache hört man auch oft die Kombination von "weil" mit "nämlich", und das könnte auch eine Ursache für die Adaption der bisher ungebräuchlichen Satzstellung sein:

> Ich erkannte ihn auf der Straße nicht, **weil** *er trug* **nämlich**
>   einen Hut und eine Sonnenbrille.

Answer (score 1):

In another thread about the same question ([Is it possible that a native German speaker doesn't put the verb to the end of the sentence after a "weil"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/13481/is-it-possible-that-a-native-german-speaker-doesnt-put-a-verb-to-the-end-of-the)) @jona mentioned that there is often a pause after the "weil". I like that observation.

It has always been the case that sometimes the subordinate clause introduced by "weil" is abandoned in mid-thought, especially if the reason to be presented is somewhat more complex, or the construction doesn't bind well to anything in the main sentence. The reason is then presented in a main sentence of its own: "Der Film ist schlecht, weil... man kann doch die Handlung nicht einfach auf die Gewalt reduzieren." The reason doesn't explicitly refer to "Film", so there is no obvious transition. Oppose that with the simpler "Der Film ist schlecht, weil er zu gewalttätig ist".

Another aspect is that a second main sentence emphasizes the presented reason. On occasion the reason for something may actually be the main topic, and the speaker may feel that sub-ordinating it may be not strong enough: "Du kannst die Wand nicht einreißen, weil dann bricht doch das ganze Haus zusammen!" (Duh.)