# Is it possible that a native German speaker doesn't put the verb to the end of the sentence after a "weil"?

Tags: sentence-structure

As I currently know, the ordering of the words is one of the strongest rules of the German grammar. Although some non-native speakers make such failures, especially if their first language has relative stricter word ordering, and doesn't know this construction.

An example for a such (as I know, bad) sentence is: *"..., weil das Verb steht in einem Hauptsatz auf Position 1."*

Recently I experienced from some sources simply saying sentences as *"weil <subj> <verb> ..."* . They were probably native speakers, although I am not sure.

Is it possible? Maybe it is some dialectical feature?

How does a such sentence sound to native speakers? Very bad, bad, or nearly nothing?

Comment: @stevenvh There was also a formatting problem in the question. Beispielsatz: "Weil das Verb steht in einem Hauptsatz auf Position 1." I extended my question with this.

Comment: I've just started studying German, but that sentence doesn't sound right to me. Not just the word order, but it isn't complete either.

Comment: @stevenvh Also not for me. I learned, after "weil" must go the verb _always_ to the end and there is no exception. But recently I heared multiple times such bad sentences, this is which I don't understand.

Comment: It's dialect. See my answer below. Don't imitate, and certainly don't write it.

Comment: @Ingmar: As a German native speaker I can assure you that it is not dialect. It's not unusual in (spoken) standard German; I'm originally from Hannover. As a relatively recent fashion (maybe 80s) it seems to be less common among old people. I remember a cartoon, maybe 20 years ago, which I unfortunately was unable to find online. A young man of the kind that finds themselves cool says "Ich rede so weil es ist modern." Most elderly people will cringe there.

Comment: As a fellow German native speaker I can assure you I do consider it such. It's common, granted, but (still) grammatically wrong. I for one don't consider it standard German.

Comment: This is what we call Denglish, Deutsch mit Englischer Grammatik (or mixture of words, like Angel-Shop). It's simply grammatically wrong in German, but as English is getting more and more prominent, this error becomes more and more frequent, especially in translated texts.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Das ist die übliche Satzstellung in den oberdeutschen Dialekten (Bairisch, Alemannisch) und dort auch nicht falsch. Leider denken viele Amateursprachenthusiasten normativ von der Schriftsprache her. Linguisten dagegen gehen von unterschiedlichen Sprachregistern aus, die nebeneinander existieren und unterschiedlichen Regeln und Gepflogenheiten folgen. Das standardsprachliche Schriftdeutsch ist nur eine Variante, und was dort richtig ist, muss nicht auch in der gesprochenen Sprache gelten. Richtige Antwort: Gesprochen ist das richtig, geschrieben, je nach Register, falsch.

Comment: @what Thanks for the information. Re-reading my comment I wondered how I could so apodictically say "it is not dialect"?? I certainly don't know all German dialects; in fact, not even one. Ah. Reading on brought back my original thought: I wanted to say "it is not *only* dialect", it occurs also in standard language, as I can wittness. This fuzzy language.

Comment: Warum? Weil deswegen!

Comment: @user4973: In der 80-Jahre-Schnulze heisst es aber nicht "weil i mog di" :-) https://www.lyrix.at/t/relax-weil-i-di-mog-938

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's becoming more and more frequent, but still considered bad form (or grammar, for that matter). Bastian Sick (of Zwiebelfisch fame) [has an opinion](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-weil-das-ist-ein-nebensatz-a-350013.html) on the matter.

Comment: Even though it's unlikely that *Der Spiegel* changes the link, it's customary here not to only link but also extract the text concerning the answer.

Comment: Sebastian Sick is the opposite of an authority on the German language. He is amongst linguists universally considered extremely uninformed.

Comment: @usr, die Großschreibung von „englisch“ in Deinem zweiten Satz ist im Deutschen falsch und wäre im Englischen richtig. Dennoch wäre es voreilig von mir, zu folgern, der Einfluss des Englischen wäre an dem Fehler schuld.

Comment: @usr, bei der Wortstellung nach „weil“ glaube ich aber nicht, dass das der Grund ist. Inversionen sind halt lästig ;)

Comment: @jona: You don't have to take Sick's word for the holy truth, but it's not automatically wrong just because he said it. The article is interesting regardless of who wrote it.

Answer (score 12):

> In der gesprochenen Sprache wird *weil* oft wie eine nebenordnende Konjunktion gebraucht, der Satzbau folgt dem Hauptsatzschema Subjekt  Prädikat  Objekt. Standardsprachlich gelten diese Satzkonstruktionen allerdings als nicht korrekt, also nicht: *Sie hat das Buch umgetauscht, weil sie hatte es schon*, sondern: *Sie hat das Buch umgetauscht, weil sie es schon hatte*.

Quelle: [Duden online](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/satzbau-nach-weil)

Comment: Das ist ein ganz typisches Beispiel für den Wandel der Sprache und für die Tatsache, dass die Regeln dem tatsächlichen Gebrauch hinterher hinken. Nicht die Regeln bestimmen was richtig oder falsch ist, sondern der lebendige Sprachgebrauch bestimmt wann eine veraltete Regel durch eine neue zu ersetzen ist.

Comment: The Duden answer is weird because German isn't an SVO language. "Dann habe ich gelacht(,) weil(,) Peter hat schon lange keiner mehr so betrunken gesehen" is not worse than "Dann habe ich gelacht(,) weil(,) schon lange hat keiner mehr Peter so betrunken gesehen." It's correct though in interpreting "weil" as colloquially allowing V2 clauses.

Comment: @jona: Richtig wäre ja auch: "Dann habe ich gelacht, weil schon lange  keiner mehr Peter so betrunken gesehen hat."

Comment: Deutsch ist schon beinahe berühmt dafür, meist mehrere Abfolgen zuzulassen - selbst innerhalb eines Sozio- und/oder Dialekts. Solche Abfolgen haben meistens jeweils ihren eigenen informationsstrukturellen Sinn.

Answer (score 5):

In any case there's a different word order for sentences with "weil" or "denn", though they have the same meaning:

> Wir können nicht kommen **weil** wir ins Kino gehen.

or

> Wir können nicht kommen **denn** wir gehen ins Kino.

The sentence after *denn* has the normal word order for an affirmative sentence, while the *weil* sentence doesn't. Maybe this is what you heard.

**edit**
Your example

> Beispielsatz: "Weil das Verb steht in einem Hauptsatz auf Position 1."

sounds wrong to me. Not only is the word order wrong, but the sentence is incomplete. It says

> "Because the verb is a main sentence is at position 1."

(Which is only true for inversion questions and imperative, BTW.)

Comment: Thus if I hear a native speaker saying a bad sentence (thus, don't putting the verb to the end after a "weil"), then it is surely big a grammatical error, and not some like an exception or a dialectical rule?

Comment: @Peter - That's what I think, but I'm not an expert (yet :-)). It sounds as bad as you would say in English "I am to the movies going". If you're lucky they understand what you mean, but it's not good at all.

Comment: It's nowhere near as bad. People use it all the time in spoken German.

Comment: @Ingmar - I hear people making errors against Dutch grammar all the time too, but that doesn't mean they're no errors. Whether you think they're bad and should be avoided is a matter of opinion, I guess. Personally, I'm kind of a grammar nazi in this respect :-).

Comment: I think there is nevertheless a comma missing. And likely a typo in the translation.

Comment: Stevenvh, you are not a native speaker and your intuitions reflect that. Weil + V2 is very common in spoken German.

Answer (score 5):

Historically, in most written, and in higher registers of spoken German, "weil" selects a verb final clause, so a sentence such as

- Weil im Hauptsatz steht das Verb an zweiter Stelle.

is perceived as at least stylistically inappropriate.

In spoken standard German, we observe a strong development towards using supposedly "subordinating conjunctions" - words such as "weil" or "obwohl", which usually introduce a verb final clause - to introduce verb second clauses. Initially, a pause (the prosodic marker of a clause boundary) would signal this usage.

- Er lacht, weil Peter wieder betrunken ist.
- Er lacht, weil (pause) Peter ist wieder betrunken.
- Peter mag ich, obwohl (pause) er ist ein Säufer.

This pause is being shortened and even dropped more and more, leading to "weil" being able to introduce both verb final and verb second clauses in spoken and colloquial written German. Presumably, what happens here is that a subordinate clause still shows verb second.

An old paper discussing the phenomenon and presenting a good selection of twenty-year old German sentences with weil+V2 is [here](http://ling.uni-konstanz.de/pages/publ/abstracts/ap075.html).

Comment: Dass Du Klammer-auf-pause-Klammer-zu schreiben musst, um Dein Anliegen zu verdeutlichen deutet m.E. schon darauf hin, dass die Sätze faul sind, sonst gäbe es ja eine richtige Schreibweise dafür. "Er lacht, denn Peter ist wieder betrunken." geht aber. :)

Comment: Orthographie hinkt normalerweise etwas (oft auch mal so ein paar 100 Jahre) hinter der gesprochenen Sprache hinterher. In diesem Falle ist die Selektion von V2-Sätzen durch "weil" ein eher neuartiges Phänomen. Allgemein sind Inferenzen von Schrift- auf gesprochene Sprache problematisch; die beiden sind nun einmal (mindestens) 2 verschiedene Sprachen.

Comment: Na ein Glück, dass es wohl noch noch ein paar hundert Jahre dauern wird, weil: Dann müssen wir nicht mehr erleben, dass es richtig ist! :) So long…

Comment: In der mündl. Sprache ist es vielerorts bereits seit einiger Zeit gut etabliert.

Answer (score 1):

"weil" is a conjunction.

You usually cannot use it in a main clause, because its purpose is to connect main clause and a subordinate clause.
But you can change the order of main clause and subordinate clause.

> Weil ich hungrig war, aß ich eine Pizza.

Comment: I'm not sure if this addresses the question. In your "weil"-part, the verb is in the end of the sentence; but the question is about that issue...

Comment: Like *Em1* says, the verb is at the end of the subordinate clause. The question was about when it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

In (spoken) Austrian German, this is not at all unusual. (Although in formal written text, we do place the verb at the end).