# Weil ich dich mag and ich mag dich

Tags: sentence-structure

I saw a caption saying "Einfach so, weil ich dich mag" My question is why is it "Ich dich mag" rather than "Ich mag dich". In other words, can i properly say "Einfach so, weil Ich mag dich" instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The answer (in a rather narrow sense)

Weil-subclauses have the verb in the last position ("..., weil ich dich mag"). But in recent german there is a tendency to put the verb in second order ("..., weil ich mag dich").

### Additional information

We are currently in a process of a changing rule; while some find it correct to use the verb in second position, others still consider it wrong. So using the respective word order is not only a question of correct or wrong, but also a matter of signalling your social background - if you want to signal that you belong to a group which takes care for the old rules of grammar (and sometimes believe that changing grammar is a sign of a decadent society as a whole), you should use "weil ich dich mag". If you don't mind that some people think you were using 'wrong' grammar, you can use "weil ich mag dich".

For this claim, for instance see [Nicholas Catasso: *Der seltsame Fall der weil-Sätze mit Verb-Zweit-Wortstellung im Deutschen:Zwischen Norm und Mündlichkeit an der Schnittstelle Syntax-Semantik-Pragmatik* In: Bavarian Working Papers in Linguistics 4: 1-20.](http://www.academia.edu/15163404/Catasso_N._2015_._Der_seltsame_Fall_der_weil-S%C3%A4tze_mit_V2-Wortstellung_im_Deutschen_Zwischen_Norm_und_M%C3%BCndlichkeit_an_der_Schnittstelle_Syntax-Semantik-Pragmatik._Bavarian_Working_Papers_in_Linguistics_4_1-20) who explicitly claims

> Das Phänomen [der Verb-zweit-Stellung im weil-Nebensatz] ist im mündlichen Gebrauch sehr verbreitet und wird trotz
> der Verschwiegenheit normativ-orientierter Sprecher (vgl. dazu Eisenberg 1993, Speyer 2011) sogar vom Duden als nicht-standardsprachliche Form akzeptiert

As CarstenS mentions in his comment, this question is sufficiently answered in the SE-thread: [Warum wird “weil” zur nebenordnenden Konjunktion?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6339/warum-wird-weil-zur-nebenordnenden-konjunktion)

Comment: People using »…, weil ich mag dich.« wanted to say »… **denn** ich mag dich.« but started the second part of the sentence with *weil* by mistake. This isn't a change in rules, it's just sloppyness and bad style.

Comment: @CarstenS Fair enough; I added the headings to reflect your point.

Comment: @Janka: Yes, and what first was the sloppyness of some and later became the sloppyness of many at the end of the day *is* nothing but the process of a changing grammar rule. I added an interesting paper which is discussing this phenomenon.

Comment: _»... weil ich mag dich.«_ Wenn das eine Tendenz ist, dann stinkt sie zum Himmel. Klingt ja fast wie _»Isch geh Schulhof!«_.

Comment: @Pollitzer Ich erlebe das hier oft; dass Leute sich über den Wandel der Sprache ärgern. Ich verstehe das nicht. Die meisten Sprachwissenschaftler finden Wandelphänomene schlicht und einfach interessant. Die Regeln sind immer ein bisschen willkürlich. Warum nun die Version per se besser sein soll, die wir gelernt haben, als wir Kinder waren, verstehe ich nicht; es ist Gewohnheit und nicht mehr...

Comment: Bei Musizieren überspringt man auch nicht ohne Verstand die Takte und klebt sie später wieder ein. Es käme auch niemand auf die Idee, einen Laienmusiker zum Maß der Dinge zu machen. Nachgeäfft wird er allenfalls, um sich über ihn lustig zu machen. Das sollte man im sprachlichen Bereich erst recht nicht tun.

Comment: @Janka Was ist denn an weil + Verb-Zweit schlecht? Wie wird die Sprache schlechter dadurch? Wie erfüllt sie ihre Funktion schlechter dadurch? Was also ist daran schlimm, außer dass es die Konvention verletzt, die Du gewohnt bist? Und was also gibt Dir das Recht, Deine Gewohnheit zum Maßstab der Dinge zu machen und Leute abzuwerten, wenn sie nicht Deiner Gewohnheit entsprechen?

Comment: Die Satzmelodie ändert sich. Deshalb brachte ich ja den Musikvergleich. Sie wird einförmiger und langweiliger. Weniger variantenreich und arm. Außerdem geht es hier eben gerade nicht um irgendein Recht, dass ich mir herausnähme. Es geht darum, dass du denjenigen, die hierher kommen und nach dem aktuellen Sprachgebrauch fragen, rätst, sich keine allzu großen Gedanken um diese Sache zu machen, weil das sowieso jeder falsch mache. Falsch! Das ist eben nicht der Fall. Falsch machen das nur Leute, die keinen Wert auf das legen, was sie sagen. Und die können nicht der Maßstab sein.

Comment: @Janka Ich habe gerade nicht geschrieben, dass es jeder so macht. Ich habe im Gegenteil darauf hingewiesen, dass es zwei Gruppen von Sprecher*innen gibt: "while some find it correct to use the verb in second position, others still consider it wrong." Und dass man mit dem jeweiligen Sprachgebrauch auch eine Zugehörigkeit zu den jeweiligen Gruppen signalisiert und dass einem dies bewusst sein soll. Du nimmst Dir schon ein Recht raus, nämlich das Recht, über die Motive anderer Leute zu spekulieren (sie legen keinen Wert auf "schöne" und "richtige" Sprache) und deren Sprachgebrauch abzuwerten.

Comment: Die Satzmelodie sich ändert. Den Musikvergleich ja deshalb ich brachte.  Sie einförmiger ist. Sie langweiliger ist. Sie weniger variantenreich ist. Sie arm ist. etc etc etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56481/discussion-between-jonathan-scholbach-and-janka).

Comment: Ich bringe es mal auf den Punkt: Fehlende Fähigkeiten sind weder eine Lebenseinstellung, noch Fortschritt, noch schutzwürdig. Dagegen kann jeder einzelne etwas tun. Es nicht zu tun ist pure Faulheit.

Comment: @Janka Menschen, die man überhaupt nicht kennt, aufgrund ihrer Andersartigkeit Faulheit zuzuschreiben, ist pure Überheblichkeit. Dagegen kann jeder einzelne was tun. scnr

Comment: Danke, dass du mir bestätigst, dass der Stich saß.

Comment: Danke fur die antwort Jonathan scholbach :)

Comment: @LorDan Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work