# Werden untergeordnete Nebensätze seltener?

Tags: word-order, subordinate-clause

Die deutsche Sprache befindet sich mit Sicherheit in einem kontinuierlichen Wandel, von einigen sogar als Sprachverfall betrachtet. Also bin ich seit einiger Zeit mehrmals auf folgende Beispiele gestoßen wie:

> "Es gibt Leute, die können keine Nebensätze mehr bilden".

Richtig heißt es: Es gibt Leute, die keine Nebensätze mehr bilden können".

> "Ich weiß, dass Menschen können vieles machen"

Richtig heißt es: Ich weiß, dass Menschen vieles machen können.

Ich habe bemerkt, dass dieser Fehler vor allem beim Satz "Es gibt -x Sache-,.." vorkommt.

Aber woher kommt denn dieser Wandel? Wird diese Struktur eines Tages als eine offizielle Regel betrachtet?

Ich bedanke mich für eure Zeit und Aufmerksamkeit.

Comment: related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6339/warum-wird-weil-zur-nebenordnenden-konjunktion

Comment: "Es war einmal ein Müller, der war arm, aber er hatte eine schöne Tochter." (Brüder Grimm) Ist das auch schon ein Beispiel für Sprachverfall?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Die Beispiele können nicht einheitlich betrachtet werden. Es handelt sich um ganz unterschiedliche Erscheinungen. Beispiel 1 enthält nach meiner Ansicht nicht einmal einen Nebensatz.

**Beispiel 1: *Es gibt Leute, die können keine Nebensätze mehr bilden.***

Dieses Phänomen ist weder neu noch ein Beispiel für "Sprachverfall", sondern altbekanntes, klassisches Inventar insbesondere der gesprochenen Sprache (mit bestimmten dialektalen Häufungen). Ob es sich bei solchen integrierten Verbzweitsätzen überhaupt um Nebensätze handelt, ist strittig - die besseren Gründe sprechen m.E. dagegen (und für die Einordnung als Hauptsatz). Recht untypisch für eine Nebensatzkonstruktion wäre insbesondere, dass die Konstruktion nur mit ganz bestimmten Antezedentien funktioniert. Vergleiche etwa falsch: **Es gibt wenige/keine Deutsche, die können überhaupt kein Deutsch.* Aber: *Es gibt viele Deutsche, die können überhaupt kein Deutsch.* Wie dem auch sei - das ist wirklich keine neue Erscheinung. Ich sehe ja auch, dass schon Beispiele aus Grimms Märchen angeführt worden sind.

Weiterführend: [Zifonun, Grammatik des Deutschen im europäischen Vergleich : Der Relativsatz](https://ids-pub.bsz-bw.de/frontdoor/index/index/docId/1424), 2001, S. 79 ff.

**Beispiel 2: *Ich weiß, dass Menschen können vieles machen.***

Das Phänomen der Hauptsatzstellung ist mir im Kontext von *dass* ebenso wie offenkundig auch den anderen bisher Antwortenden nicht bekannt, weder aus der Literatur noch aus dem Alltag. Der Satz erscheint mithin agrammatisch. Zur Herkunft kann ich insofern nichts beitragen.

Es gibt allerdings - darauf hat oben auch ein Kommentator schon hingewiesen - bei einigen wenigen Subjunktoren eine entsprechende Tendenz, Hauptsatzstrukturen einzuleiten, etwa bei *weil* und *obwohl*. Beispiel aus dem Kommentar:

> Der Elefant geht zum Tümpel, weil, er ist durstig.

Dieses Phänomen aus der gesprochenen Sprache hat sprachwissenschaftlich bereits sehr umfassend Beachtung gefunden, um nicht zu sagen: Die Literatur ist inzwischen kaum noch überschaubar. Am jahrzehntealten Diskurs lässt sich, nebenbei bemerkt, auch erkennen, dass die Erscheinung zumindest so neu nicht sein kann.

Die ganze Konstruktion weist von Nahem betrachtet - und das ist auch der Grund für die Publikationsfülle - eine äußerst komplexe sprachliche Struktur auf. Mitnichten handelt es sich, wie es in der Frage ein Wenig anklingt, um eine Art Alternativform für Leute, die zu dumm sind, um Nebensätze zu bilden. Ein Beispiel: Das *weil*-mit-Verbzweitstellung-Konnekt (*weil*-V2-Konnekt) wird nur dann breit akzeptiert, wenn es auf sein externes Konnekt folgt. Also etwa: *Der Elefant geht zum Tümpel, weil, er ist durstig.* Aber nicht: **Weil, er ist durstig, geht der Elefant zum Tümpel. *Der Elefant, weil, er ist durstig, geht zum Tümpel.* Auch eine Einbettung in Interrogativsätze scheidet aus: **Ist der Elefant zum Tümpel gegangen, weil, er ist durstig?*

Die Liste der spezifischen semantischen und syntaktischen Bedingungen und Eigenschaften ließe sich noch lange fortsetzen. Ein derartiges Komplexitätspattern deutet im Allgemeinen nicht auf "Sprachverfall" hin. Ganz wichtig ist in diesem Zusammenhang auch, dass die Bedeutung von V2-Konnekt und VL-Konnekt ganz offenbar nicht identisch ist. Beachte etwa das folgende Beispiel von [Antomo/Steinbach (2010)](https://goescholar.uni-goettingen.de/bitstream/handle/1/11587/zfsw.2010.001.pdf?sequence=5&isAllowed=y):

1. Es hat einen Unfall gegeben, weil der Airbag ist aufgegangen.
2. Es hat einen Unfall gegeben, weil der Airbag aufgegangen ist.

In (1) wurde der *weil*-Satz von 35% der Befragten als propositional aufgefasst, von 55% als epistemisch; in (2) wurde er von 72% der Befragten als propositional aufgefasst und von 23% als epistemisch. Soll heißen: (1) vermittelt offenbar den allermeisten, dass nicht etwa das Aufgehen des Airbags den Unfall verursacht hat, sondern dass aus dem Aufgehen des Airbags darauf geschlossen wird, dass es wohl einen Unfall gegeben hat. Bei (2) ist es umgekehrt.

Zusammengefasst: Bereits die unterschiedlichen Voraussetzungen und die komplexen Strukturen verweisen darauf, dass hier nicht einfach bloß "Fehler" gemacht werden. Hinzu kommt: Die Bedeutung ist aus Sprechersicht auch gar nicht identisch.

Comment: Das war aber mal eine tiefgründige Antwort, weil, sie ist so differenziert. (Das meine ich jetzt epistemisch, aber auch propositional.)

Comment: PS jedoch: Hast du im vorletzten Absatz nicht *epistemisch* und *propositional* verwechselt? Ich hätte getipt, dass die meisten Leute Satz 2 für eher propositional (oder von mir aus: kausal) verstehen würden ("Es hat einen Unfall gegeben in der Folge dessen dass der Airbag aufgegangen ist"), und dass bei Satz 1 mehr Leute das Epistemische heraushören würden: "Es hat einen Unfall gegeben (ich vermute das hier mal) weil, der Airbag ist aufgegangen [= befindet sich jetzt im geöffneten Zustand]"

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Genau so ist es. Ich habe versehentlich (1) und (2) vertauscht. Ist nun korrigiert, danke für den Hinweis.

Answer (score 3):

Nicht alle Beispiele sind neue Erscheinungen.

> Es gibt Leute, die können keine Nebensätze mehr bilden

wäre mindestens im Schwäbischen die natürlichere Formulierung.

> Ich weiß, dass Menschen können vieles machen

Das ist kein Sprachwandel. Das ist falsch und sollte bei Muttersprachlern nicht vorkommen.

> Der Elefant geht zum Tümpel, weil, er ist durstig.

Das ist möglicherweise eine neuere Erscheinung. Die Gründe könnten das Internet oder auch die Präsenz bildungsferner Schichten oder von Dialekten in den Medien sein. Ich weiß aber nicht, ob das in irgendwelchen Dialekten so verwendet wird.

"Weil" wird aus meiner Sicht dem "denn" bevorzugt, weil es ausdrucksstärker ist, speziell beim Sprechen.
Zum Vergleich:
"Weil" wird aus meiner Sicht dem "denn" bevorzugt, denn es ist ausdrucksstärker, speziell beim Sprechen.
Dass die Subst/Verb-Ordnung nicht angepasst wird, liegt möglicherweise daran, dass das Gehirn einen zusätzlichen Aufwand dafür betreiben muss. Das dürfte auch beim Zuhören einfacher sein. Mir kommen da Fußballer-Interviews nach dem Spiel in den Sinn.

Für mich auch interessant:

> Darf ich Kuchen?

Das habe ich früher so nicht gehört, war aber damals eher süddeutschen Dialekten ausgesetzt.

Comment: Genau. In Grimms Märchen vom Anfang des 19Jhds gibt es den Satz: „Vor einem großen Walde lebte ein Holzhacker mit seiner Frau, der hatte nur ein einziges Kind, das war ein Mädchen von drei Jahren. “

Comment: @Ludi   Ich lese diese Sätze in Grimms Märchensprache nicht als Nebensätze (mit dann falscher Wortreihenfolge); vielmehr sind sie für mich aneinandergereihte Hauptsätze. Rügenswert wäre dann allenfalls die schludrige Interpunktion. Ein ordentlicher Punkt wäre gut gewesen. Der hätte auch durch einen Strichpunkt ersetzt werden können.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Auch ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob ein Nebensatz vorliegt. Aber es ist die selbe Konstruktion wie in der Frage, nicht war?

Comment: Wenn man den Satz zu „Vor einem großen Walde lebte ein Holzhacker mit seiner Frau, der nur ein einziges Kind hatte, das ein Mädchen von drei Jahren war. “ umbaut, dann scheint er auch nach der heutigen Grammatik richtig zu sein. Der erste Nebensatz klingt für mich noch richtig, der zweite aber nicht mehr. Im schwäbischen wird aber auch noch auf das Präteritum verzichtet und das Perfekt bevorzugt. Da geht das dann nicht mehr gut. Ich denke heute sind solche Nebensatzverkettungen unüblich. Man findet hauptsächlich Verschachtelungen.

Comment: Schließt man aber von meiner schwäbischen Begründung rückwärts, dann müsste auch der Grimm-Satz so erlaubt sein.

Comment: Bei Muttersprachlern nicht vorkommen  - auch bei Muttersprachlern anderer nah verwandten westgermanischen Sprachen?