# Relativsatz mit dialektaler/umgs. Wortfolge oder eigenständiger Satz?

Tags: sentence-structure, dialect, colloquial, relative-clause, relative-pronoun

Ein Dialektsprecher produzierte mal so einen Satz auf Standarddeutsch:

> Es gibt Sachen, **die kann man nicht verstehen.**

Ich glaube, semantisch gesehen dürfte das ein Relativsatz sein, aber bin etwas verunsichert ob man den Satz etwas anders verstehen kann, nämlich als 2 Hauptsätze. Welche semantische Interpretation wäre hier richtiger und inwieweit ist dieses Phänomen in der gegenwärtigen Umgangssprache verbreitet?

Comment: _"manche meinen
lechts und rinks
kann man nicht velwechsern
werch ein llltum"_ Source: https://www.misesde.org/?p=11566

Comment: Auf die politische Dimension will ich gar nicht erst eingehen.

Comment: Nimmst du etwa an, keine Fragen bzgl. der Umganggsprache dürfen sein, da inherent "opinion based"?

Comment: Ich nehme immer _zwei Stöck Zöcker_ ;-).

Comment: Wie du willst. Dennoch sehe ich keinen Grund dafür, dass die Übersetzungsanfragen die du gerne beantwortest sein dürfen und meine Frage nicht.

Comment: Mit Dialekt hat das schon mal nichts zu tun.

Comment: Ein Argument contra Nebensatz hier: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/45955/35111

Comment: @DavidVogt sehr interessanter Beitrag, danke.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ : Aber mit Umgangssprache. Anderes Beispiel: _Es gibt Sachen, die gibt's nicht._ (Oberflächlich paradox, gemeint ist "Manche Sachen gibt es, obwohl es sie eigentlich - nach den Regeln der Vernunft, der Wahrscheinlichkeit - gar nicht geben dürfte.)

Comment: Vergleich auch "Sachen gibts ...", insb. "Sachen gibts, die gibts gar nicht".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Relativsätze können restriktiv sein. Im folgenden Beispiel erkennt man die Restriktivität daran, daß der Sprecher mehr als zwei Zähne haben kann.

> Ich habe zwei Zähne, die wehtun.

Bei zwei aufeinanderfolgen Hauptsätzen ist keine restriktive Interpretation möglich; der Sprecher hat genau zwei Zähne. (Damit der Unterschied zwischen den beiden folgenden Varianten deutlich wird, habe ich Pfeile für den Stimmverlauf ergänzt.)

> Ich habe zwei Zähne.↘  Die tun weh. ↘

Beim V2-Relativsatz ist, wie beim regulären Relativsatz, eine restriktive Interpretation möglich: der Sprecher kann mehr als zwei Zähne haben.

> Ich habe zwei Zähne, → die tun weh. ↘

Comment: ganz nebenbei: hättest du einen Begriff für die VE-Stellung von Adverbien wie "jetzt", z.B. "ich habe das gemacht heute"?

Comment: @Dan [Ausklammerung](http://mediawiki.ids-mannheim.de/VarGra/index.php/Ausklammerung)

Comment: Danke. Wusste nicht richtig ob ich dazu noch eine Question stellen sollte.

Comment: @Dan, eine Quä-stion? Häh? :-)

Answer (score 11):

***I. Allgemeines; Relativsatz oder Hauptsatz?***

> *Es gibt Sachen, **die kann man nicht verstehen.***

Gärtner (2001) führt für Sätze wie den fettgedruckten die Bezeichnung **integrierte Verbzweitsätze (IV2-Sätze)** ein. Andere bezeichnen sie auch als **relativische Verbzweitsätze**. Sie sind - jedenfalls heute - wohl ein Phänomen der gesprochenen (und allenfalls noch der geschriebenen informellen) Sprache (Zifonun 2001: 79; Gärtner 2001: 97). In der sprachwissenschaftlichen Literatur gibt es unterschiedliche Ansichten zu der Frage, ob es sich dabei um Relativ- oder Hauptsätze handelt. Uns wird es nicht gelingen, diese Streitfrage hier zu entscheiden. Die meisten Autoren sehen IV2-Sätze aber heute (mit guten Gründen) eher als Hauptsätze denn als Relativsätze an.(*) Ich komme darauf gleich zurück.

Einige Merkmale von IV2-Sätzen:

1. Das Denotat des IV2-Satzes entspricht dem des Bezugselements (hier: *Sachen*). Der IV2-Satz ist in den Gesamtsatz integriert und bildet mit ihm eine Informationseinheit.
2. IV2-Sätze sind in den Matrixsatz intonatorisch integriert (daher auch der Name). Vor dem IV2-Satz gibt es keine finale prosodische Grenzmarkierung. Der Intonationsbogen (ansteigender Tonhöhenverlauf) wird über den einleitenden demonstrativen Ausdruck hinweg aufrechterhalten. Siehe im Detail Gärtner (2001) (die Arbeit gründet im Wesentlichen auf den Besonderheiten der Intonationsstruktur).
3. In syntaktischer Hinsicht sind IV2-Sätze extraponiert, das heißt sie stehen immer ganz rechts im Satz (im Nachfeld). (Das fällt in Ihrem Satz nicht auf, aber betrachten Sie etwa das folgende Beispiel: [Mit Relativsatz:] *Mein Kollege soll einen Sohn haben, der den Zauberwürfel in zwei Minuten lösen kann.* Oder auch: *Mein Kollege soll einen Sohn, der den Zauberwürfel in zwei Minuten lösen kann, haben.* [Mit IV2-Satz:] *Mein Kollege soll einen Sohn haben, der kann den Zauberwürfel in zwei Minuten lösen.* Aber nie: **Mein Kollege soll einen Sohn, der kann den Zauberwürfel in zwei Minuten lösen, haben.*)
4. IV2-Sätze werden immer von einigen wenigen demonstrativen Ausdrücken eingeleitet: *der, die, das*, interessanterweise auch *da* (siehe etwa Pafel (2011: 84): *Es gibt Länder, da kostet das Bier ein Vermögen.*). (Das ist deswegen interessant, weil *da* anders als *der, die, das* gar nicht zur Klasse der Relativpronomen gehört.) *w*-Pronomen scheiden aus.
5. Das Bezugselement unterliegt umfassenden Einschränkungen. Wie man diese jeweils generalisieren kann, ist im Einzelnen umstritten und insgesamt wohl auch eine recht komplexe Angelegenheit, daher gebe ich hier nur ein paar konkrete Beispiele: Die unbestimmten Quantoren *alle, wenige, keine, die meisten* sind etwa allesamt inkompatibel mit der IV2-Struktur (also etwa nicht: **Es gibt wenige Sachen, die kann man nicht verstehen.*). Ein Bezug auf Nominalphrasen mit bestimmtem Artikel oder Demonstrativum scheidet aus (**Ich kenne den König, der hat drei Töchter.*).

Aus meiner Sicht sprechen vor allem einige der Einschränkungen in (5) gegen eine Einordnung als Relativsatz. Proponenten einer Einordnung als Relativsatz würden freilich eher auf (1) und (2) verweisen. Letztlich kann man sich darüber natürlich trefflich streiten. Birkner (2006: 233) meint dazu:

> "Wo verläuft nun eine kategoriale Grenze? Handelt es sich bei
>   Mensch-Konstruktionen mit V-2-Sätzen um subordinative, hypotaktische
>   Relativsätze oder um koordinative, parataktische Hauptsätze? Ersterem
>   widerspricht die Verbstellung und Zweiterem der enge
>   semantisch-pragmatische Bezug, der zwischen den beiden Syntagmen
>   besteht. Letztlich entscheidet auch die terminologische Tradition oder
>   Grammatikkonzeption darüber, ob man die beschriebenen Phänomene als
>   abhängige Hauptsätze fasst, ob man sie wie GÄRTNER (1998) als
>   'integrated V2' bezeichnet oder ob man von Relativsätzen mit
>   V-2-Stellung spricht."

***II. Bedeutungsunterschiede?***

Zur Frage nach etwaigen Bedeutungsunterschieden zum "gewöhnlichen" Relativsatz (in den Fällen, in denen es beide Möglichkeiten gibt): In den meisten Fällen unterscheidet sich die Bedeutung wohl nicht, aufgrund der distinkten Eigenschaften von IV2-Sätzen kann es bisweilen aber gewisse Unterschiede geben.

- Beispiel aus Abraham (2016: 129): *Hans will ein Mädchen heiraten, das aus Schweden ist.* Ob ein solches Mädchen existiert, wissen wir nicht - möglicherweise kennt Hans noch nicht einmal irgendein Mädchen aus Schweden. Hingegen: *Hans will ein Mädchen heiraten, das ist aus Schweden.* Hier muss das Mädchen existieren. Der Verbletzt-Relativsatz erzwingt keinen Existenzschluss, der IV2-Satz offenbar schon.
- Da IV2-Sätze gegenüber Relativsätzen weniger Interpretationsmöglichkeiten zulassen, erweisen sich jene, auch wenn sie gebildet werden können, in manchen Zusammenhängen als ungeeignet. Man betrachte exemplarisch die folgenden zwei Sprechsituationen, die in Ebert et al. (2005: 431) konstruiert werden:
  (1) [A sagt:] *Kennst du viele Linguisten?* [B antwortet:] *Ich kenne viele Linguisten, die über IV2 forschen.* Was verstanden wird als: Eigentlich nicht, aber ich kenne viele Linguisten, die über IV2 forschen.
  (2) [A sagt:] *Hast du schon mit vielen IV2-Forschern zusammengearbeitet?* [B antwortet:] *Ich kenne viele Linguisten, die über IV2 forschen.* Was verstanden wird als: Zusammengearbeitet nicht, aber ich kenne viele Linguisten, die über IV2 forschen.
  Obwohl ein korrespondierender IV2-Satz gebildet werden kann (*die forschen über IV2*), würde damit weder die Frage in (1) noch die in (2) beantwortet, weil die Interpretationen, die wir bei den oben genannten Relativsätzen als Sprecher vornehmen, in diesem Fall versperrt wären. Die bloße Feststellung, viele IV2-Forscher zu kennen, kann (1) und (2) nicht beantworten.

***III. Häufigkeit***

Mir sind keine größeren empirischen Arbeiten dazu bekannt. Lenzhofer (2017) sammelt drei Teilkorpora zur gesprochenen Sprache in Osttirol (jugendliche Dialektsprecher [acht Transkripte mit Freizeitkommunikation von 22 Sprechern], erwachsene Dialektsprecher [Gespräche von insgesamt 18 Sprechern], erwachsene Standardsprecher [98 Transkripte von TV-Sendungen]) und findet dort fast 700 Relativkonstruktionen. Bei den Standardsprechern herrschen die Verbletztsätze klar vor (8 Verbzweitsätze mit *der/die/das* gegenüber 333 Verbletztsätzen mit *der/die/das*). Wenn man nur die Dialektsprecher betrachtet, sind es hingegen 6 Verbzweitsätze mit *der/die/das* gegenüber 27 Verbletztsätzen mit *der/die/das*. Hinzu kommt eine nicht geringe Zahl von Fällen, die als mehrdeutig gewertet wurden.

Das Phänomen ist, nebenbei bemerkt, uralt. Siehe Axel-Tober (2012: 221ff) für Belege aus dem Mittelhochdeutschen.

---

<sup>(*) Relativ offenkundig ist freilich, dass IV2-Sätze - anders als früher vereinzelt behauptet - keine bloße orthographische Variante "normaler" Hauptsätze sind. Man sieht das ganz gut in Beispielen wie *Mein Kollege hat einen Sohn, der kann den Zauberwürfel in zwei Minuten lösen.* Würde man das Komma einfach durch einen Punkt ersetzen, wäre klar, dass der Kollege insgesamt nur einen Sohn hat; die Version mit Komma lässt hingegen offen, ob es auch noch weitere Söhne gibt ("restriktive Interpretation").</sup>

---

<sup>Literatur: Abraham (2016), Zum grundsätzlichen Unterschied von Ereignissubjunktion (de re) und Prämissensubjunktion (de dicto) im Westgermanischen, Glottotheory 7(2): 113–136, https://doi.org/10.1515/glot-2016-0011; Axel-Tober (2012), (Nicht-)kanonische Nebensätze im Deutschen: Synchrone und diachrone Aspekte, De Gruyter; Birkner (2006), (Relativ-)Konstruktionen zur Personenattribuierung: ‚ich bin n=mensch der...’, in: Günthner/Imo, Konstruktionen in der Interaktion, De Gruyter, 205–236, https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110894158.205; Ebert/Endriss/Gärtner (2007), An Information Structural Account of German Integrated Verb Second Clauses, Research on Language and Computation 5(4): 415–434, https://doi.org/10.1007/s11168-007-9038-y; Gärtner (2001), Are there V2 relative clauses in German?, Journal of Comparative Germanic Linguistics 3(2): 97–141, https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1011432819119; Pafel (2011), Einführung in die Syntax, Metzler; Zifonun (2001), Grammatik des Deutschen im europäischen Vergleich: Der Relativsatz, https://nbn-resolving.org/urn:nbn:de:bsz:mh39-14241.</sup>

Comment: Sehr gute Antwort. Siehe auch https://bop.unibe.ch/linguistik-online/article/view/1599/2702

Comment: Zu Punkt I.4.: Nach meiner Beobachtung ist **da** in der Umgangssprache (funktional) so etwas wie ein Allround-Pronomen für Orts- (_da war ich noch nie_, s. DWDS I.1.b) und Zeitbezüge (_Donnerstag? Da kann ich nicht_; s. DWDS II.2) und auch eine Art Situationspronomen bzw. unspezifisches Anküpfungspronomen mit einer Bedeutung wie "in so einer / in dieser Situation // in so einem / in diesem Fall" (_da stehe / stand ich dann ziemlich blöd da_; s. DWDS III.) _Da_ wundert mich das Vorkommen in IV2-Sätzen nicht. - (https://www.dwds.de/wb/da)

Comment: Für mich sehr 'spannend' zu lesen (leider gibt es ja für 'interessant' im Deutschen keine brauchbare Alternative). Toll, dass die Literaturangaben verlinkt und online nachlesbar sind!

Comment: Re zu I.4) "Ich weiß nicht was soll es bedeuten", altes Liedgut.

Answer (score 0):

Für einen Relativsatz hat er die falsche Satzstellung. Sollte sein: Es gibt Sachen, die man nicht verstehen kann.

Wie wär es also als Kompromis mit einem Semikolon, statt einem Komma: Es gibt Sachen; die kann man nicht verstehen.

Nebenbei gesagt: Die Bedeutung ist völlig unabhängig davon, ob es zwei Hauptsätze oder ein Haupt- und ein Nebensatz sind.

Comment: völlig unabhängig - intuitiv merke ich da eine Bedeutungverschiebung, als ob man versuchte, etwas extra zu betonen.

Answer (score -3):

Hier liegt ein beinahe ganz normaler Relativsatz--ohne V2 vor.

*man* muss dafür als Dativobjekt verstanden werden:

> Mach man Abflug.
>
> Laber ma' kein Müll. (*oft mit* mal *verwechselt*).
>
> Mach mir keinen Ärger

Zwar ist *?jemandem etwas verstehen* nicht regulär, aber bevor einen das stört, stört doch eher, dass kein Subjekt mehr vorläge, wenn man mal davon absieht, dass *die (Sachen)* ganz offensichtlich das Thema und zuvor auch das Subjekt ist, denn die Flektion des Verbs, *kann*, widerspricht der Deutung des Plurals als grammatisches Subjekt.

Auf hochsprachlicge Grammatik nach Schema F (mit Passierschein 17) kommt es aber nicht an, sondern auf die Herleitung, sofern das Schema alt-ererbt ist.

Vergleiche: *Es gibt einenen Mann, da m[an] nicht zu nah gekommen werden will*; ist etwas konstruiert, ja. Der Punkt ist *da-m* wirkt effektiv als Dativ, vgl *dem*. Die Bildung von zusammengefügten Relativpronomen ist gut bezeugt.

Details bleibe ich leider schuldig, da nun sicher unzählige weitere Einflüsse eine Rolle spielen.