# Does the verb have to come at last place in a subordinate clause?

Tags: verb, sentence-structure

This is from a podcast transcription:

> Es gibt aber eine Sache, die ist im deutschen Bankwesen anders als im Rest der Welt.

Shouldn't it be

- "...die im deutschen Bankwesen anders IST als im Rest der Welt."

or

- "...die im deutschen Bankwesen anders als im Rest der Welt IST."?

Comment: In German: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/55052/35111

Comment: @DavidVogt So here it is actually two separate sentences? It is equivalent to "Es gibt aber eine Sache, (und) sie ist im deutschen Bankwesen anders als im Rest der Welt."?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, yes, the finite verb has to stay in last place.

However, as usual there are a number of exceptions to this.

- Comparisons with certain conjunctions are exempt: "... weil er sich wehrte *wie* ein Berserker."
- Vocatives (terms of address) can go wherever they want: "Wenn Sie mich fragen, *Frau Will*, ..."
- Coordination can attach pretty much everywhere, including at the end of a subclause: "Er nannte einen Grund, der nicht sehr überzeugend war *und* niemandem einleuchtete.'"
- Certain prepositions that function as conjunctions: "Ich bin hier, weil ich die rote Pille nahm *statt* der blauen."

Comment: But this still does not explain why "ist" comes before "im deutschen Bankwesen anders". i think maybe it is two separate sentences where the "die" in the beginning of the second sentence means the same as "sie", refering back to "Sache" but not initiating a subordinate clause but another main sentence.