# When does definite article refer to personal pronouns?

Tags: meaning-in-context, article

> "Es war einmal eine alte Schweinemutter, die hatte drei kleine Schweinchen.".

By what grammatical rule causes die to mean 'her' in this sentence?

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/29013/when-is-er-replaceable-with-der

Comment: "die" is very probably not an article here, but a relative pronoun. (Please add the complete quote to show that).

Comment: @tofro: My first thought was demonstrative pronoun; wouldn't a relative pronoun put the verb at the end?. In any case, it is hard to tell from what's given. This must be a duplicate several times over either way; there are probably lots of answers here talking about relative and demonstrative pronouns.

Comment: Whatever it is, it certainly doesn't mean "her" here?

Comment: @RDBury My guess is the original quote was "Es war einmal eine alte Schweinemutter, die hatte drei kleine Schweinchen.". Here, "die" is obviously a relative pronoun. Thus I was asking for the full quote.

Comment: that's right @tofro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Es war einmal eine Schweinemutter, **die** hatte drei kleine Schweinchen.

Here, "die" is the *relative pronoun* in the subclause (after the comma) that relates to the subject of the main clause ("Schweinemutter").

It actually doesn't mean "her", but rather "who". It translates as

> There once was a pig mother **who** had three little piglets.

German "die" can be a bit tricky, because it can be an article, a demonstrative, or a relative pronoun. Here, it's the latter.

Comment: How do you explain the position of the verb in what you identify as a relative clause?

Comment: @CarstenS https://www.slm.uni-hamburg.de/ren/media/pdf/ihden-gastvortrag-v2-rs-2016-01-19.pdf "Ausnahmen"

Comment: Danke. Für den Anwender ist es im Endeffekt ja auch egal, welche Art von Pronomen das ist.

Comment: Zu den V2-Relativsätzen siehe auch https://german.stackexchange.com/a/55064/35111.

Comment: @CarstenS Das ist vor allem deswegen egal, weil sich die Sprachwissenschaftler hier ja auch nicht einig sind ;)