# Confusing word order of verbs in Nebensatz

Tags: sentence-structure, subordinate-clause

> Ich kenne einen Hund, der sprechen kann.
>
> Ich kenne einen Hund, der kann sprechen.

Why are these two sentences, which mean the same, idiomatic in the two different word orders?

Comment: Another example: *Ich weiss nicht, was soll es bedeuten.* vs. *Ich weiss nicht, was es bedeuten soll.*

Comment: In German: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/55052

Comment: "Ich weiss nicht, was soll es bedeuten." is not correct unless it is a question: "Was soll es bedeuten?".

Comment: @ChristelleAugustin perhaps permissible in poetry? https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Lore-Ley

Answer (score 4):

The difference between your two example sentences is: the first one is a "Hauptsatz" (main sentence?) with a "Relativsatz". The second one is a succession of (two) main sentences.

Let us start with the first one: the *Relativsatz* works like an *Adjektiv* for the *Objekt* of the main sentence:

> Main sentence: [Ich (*Subjekt*)] [kenne (*Prädikat*)] [einen Hund (Objekt)].

The *Objekt* could contain one or more *Adjektive* to further describe its properties:

> Ich kenne [einen *großen, grünen, einbeinigen (, ...)* Hund].

Instead of (or in addition to) these *Adjektive* there can be one or more *Relativsätze*, which act alike. They also describe further properties - ones which are too complex to have a single word for it:

> Ich kenne einen [*großen* (Adjektiv)] Hund, [*der sprechen kann* (Relativsatz)].

Notice that in *Relativsätzen* the verb (here: "können"/"kann") always goes last.

Let us get to the second sentence: This is simply a list of two main sentences. The comma is there to separate the two. There are other possible means of separating such (lists of) main sentences: "und", "oder", "aber", and so on. It would also be possible to separate them by a full stop:

> Ich kenne einen Hund, der kann sprechen.
> Ich kenne einen Hund. Der kann sprechen.

I forego the exact analysis for the first part (see above), the second sentence parses out like this:

> [Der (Subjekt) [kann sprechen (Prädikat)].

Words like "können" (there is also "müssen", "dürfen", "lassen", "mögen", ...) are so-called "Modalverben", which modify another verb, which is attached in *Infinitv*. For instance:

> Der kann sprechen.
> Der spricht.

Comment: The possibility of a restrictive interpretation distinguishes this type of integrated clause from sequences of main clauses; see the answers to https://german.stackexchange.com/q/55052/35111.

Comment: @DavidVogt: it is true, modern scholars argue about this being a main sentence. I just didn't think it would help the O/P to relate that (rather advanced) discussion here. On the other hand, "der" is not only an article but also a *Demonstrativpronomen* and is used as such here. The  "der" in "Der spricht." will always reference something said before. i.e. X wants to say something, but Y interjects: "Am Wort ist Z. *Der* spricht."

Answer (score 1):

Ich kenne einen Hund, der sprechen kann.
"Der" is used as a relative pronoun -> Nebensatz -> verb at the end.
Translation: I know a dog that can speak.

Ich kenne einen Hund, der kann sprechen.
"Der" is used as a demonstrative pronoun (like "dieser") -> Hauptsatz
https://studyflix.de/deutsch/demonstrativpronomen-3437
I know a dog, that/this one can speak.

Be careful, "der" has different meanings!

Regarding:
Another example: Ich weiss nicht, was soll es bedeuten. vs. Ich weiss nicht, was es bedeuten soll. –
First one:
Ich weiß [es] nicht. Was soll es bedeuten?
Second one:
Ich weiß nicht, was es bedeuten soll.

Assuming you are an English native speaker, you have probably never thought about:

I want to know! Who **is** he?
I want to know who he **is**.

As you can see, exactly the same structure as in German. All of a sudden, the verb has to be at the end. :)

Comment: Regarding *Ich weiss nicht, was soll es bedeuten*: is the use by Heine a poetic distortion of grammar or of punctuation? (aka *Ich weiss nicht. Was soll es bedeuten, dass ich so traurig bin?*)

Comment: There is actually nothing special about the sentence! It is possible to use the comma like he did: https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma - Rule D117
But be careful: The history of the German language is different from most other European languages. The country "Germany" was proclaimed in 1871, this is one of the reasons why we have so many dialects. For a long time, there was no standard grammar .... Watch his: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_zaFZ7eXo0 to get a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example the words in the Nebensatz are all more or less same weighted when someone reads the sentence. In the second example the last word can be more emphasized. Which would make the speaking dog in the first sentence something thats more or less normal and appears like that in nature. But the second sentence has the potential to emphasize that weirdness a little more. Nevertheless, both are correct. It is just a little game with the weight of different words in sentences.

Your second example is actually wrong, or grammatically not very pretty. The first sentence "Ich weiss nicht, was soll es bedeuten." wouldn't be used as it sounds weird and is overly complicated in providing its message.

Comment: Nitpicking: "your second example" was actually provided by a commenter, not the OP. Also, it is the opening line of a classic poem by Heine: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Lore-Ley. (Heine notwithstanding, I agree with you that "Ich weiß nicht, was soll es bedeuten" sounds much less grammatical than the alternative.)