Relativsatz In Spoken Language
"Jabbar ist Archäologe, der kam vor zehn Jahren nach Köln aus Syrien."
I started listening to News Podcast and the above sentence has been said. "der" after the comma is a Relativpronomen if I understand correctly, however the verb comes in second position. Does that happen frequently in spoken German?

See (in German) https://german.stackexchange.com/q/55052.

I think, in this case, "der" is a demonstrative pronoun (Demonstrativpronomen). It can be replaced with "dieser" without changing the meaning (although this might be uncommon).

Jabbar ist Archäologe, der kam vor zehn Jahren nach Köln aus Syrien.
(Jabbar ist Archäologe, dieser kam vor zehn Jahren nach Köln aus Syrien.)

In spoken language it is not even clear if there is a comma or a separate sentence.

Jabbar ist Archäologe. Der kam vor zehn Jahren nach Köln aus Syrien.
(Jabbar ist Archäologe. Dieser kam vor zehn Jahren nach Köln aus Syrien.)

If it would be a relative pronoun, it could be replaced with "welcher", and the word order would have to be different. As for "dieser", the variant with "welcher" is uncommon.

Jabbar ist Archäologe, der vor zehn Jahren nach Köln aus Syrien kam.
(Jabbar ist Archäologe, welcher vor zehn Jahren nach Köln aus Syrien kam.)

But this sounds a bit strange without an article for Archäologe, so in fact I would use

Jabbar ist der Archäologe, der vor zehn Jahren nach Köln aus Syrien kam.

or

Jabbar ist ein Archäologe, der vor zehn Jahren nach Köln aus Syrien kam.


You are looking at two separate main clauses, there is no relative pronoun and no subordinate sentence:

Jabbar ist Archäologe, der kam vor zehn Jahren nach Köln aus Syrien.

You can replace the comma by a full stop without changing of meaning:

Jabbar ist Archäologe. Der kam vor zehn Jahren nach Köln aus Syrien.

In both cases the 'der' a demonstrative pronoun which refers to the subject in the preceeding sentence. Of course you can rephrase it to a main clause with a subordinate clause using a relative pronoun (which incidentially would also be 'der'), and you then will find the expected word order with finite verb last in the subordinate sentence. As already mentioned by Bodo in his answer, inserting a 'der' in the main clause makes it sound more natural (and implies that this person has been spoken about some way before):

Jabbar ist (der) Archäologe, der vor zehn Jahren nach Köln aus Syrien kam.


This is the correct answer IMHO. If I'd had to write down that spoken text, I'd actually separate the two phrases by a semicolon to indicate that they're tighly interwoven by the "der": Jabbar ist... ; der kam vor zehn Jahren...

This phenomenon is not uncommon in spoken language.
I am not sure it is a relative pronoun, though. It could also be understood as a personal pronoun (instead of using er) or a demonstrative pronoun, and the part after the comma would be a regularly shaped second main clause. I am sure there is some scientific research on this, but I can't reference it for you, because I am not an expert in the field.
