# "Weil ich weiß die Antwort nicht."

Tags: sentence-structure

Zur Einleitung ein kurzer Dialog.

> 1a) Warum sagst du nichts? - Weil ich die Antwort nicht weiß.
>
> 1b) Warum sagst du nichts? - * Weil ich weiß die Antwort nicht.

Der Nebensatz in 1b) ist ungrammatisch, aber darum geht es hier nicht.

Das Gleiche in leicht abgeänderter Form:

> 2a) Ich sage nichts, weil ich die Antwort nicht weiß.
>
> 2b) Ich sage nichts, * weil ich weiß die Antwort nicht.

Auch der Nebensatz in 2b) ist ungrammatisch.

Fragt man, wie es zu den Fehlern in 1b) und 2b) kommt, lautet die Antwort in aller Regel: Zum einen liegt offensichtlich eine syntaktische Kontamination vor, zum anderen weiß man, dass parataktische Konstruktionen einfacher zu verarbeiten sind als hypotaktische. So weit, so gut.

Haupt- und Nebensatz aus 2a) und 2b) nun in umgekehrter Reihenfolge:

> 3a) Weil ich die Antwort nicht weiß, sage ich nichts.
>
> 3b) * Weil ich weiß die Antwort nicht, sage ich nichts.

Der Nebensatz in 3b) ist im selben Maße ungrammatisch wie die in 1b) und 2b). Während Analogbildungen zu 1b) und 2b) vermutlich schon milliardenfach vorgekommen sind und tagtäglich erneut vorkommen, kommt 3b) **nicht** vor. **Nie**. Wie ließe sich das erklären?

---

N.B.: Es ist vorstellbar, dass die konkrete Frage zu einem eng eingegrenzten Phänomen einigen zu hoch ist - sie ist deswegen jedoch nicht "too broad". To whom it may concern.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6339/warum-wird-weil-zur-nebenordnenden-konjunktion?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warum wird "weil" zur nebenordnenden Konjunktion?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6339/warum-wird-weil-zur-nebenordnenden-konjunktion)

Comment: Ich erwarte zwar keine gute Antwort, aber die Frage ist mir nicht unklar, und sie ist auch kein Duplikat.

Comment: "Weil ich die Antwort nicht kenne" ist besser, aber die deutsche Sprache ist jetzt leider in einem suboptimalen Zustand. Mehr kannst Du darüber hier lesen: http://bastiansick.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/2013_bildungsverlag_eins_sprechen_schreiben_gestalten_1-print.pdf

Comment: The closure is for "unclear", so make you question more clear. And make also much better visible, how it differs from the dupe candidate. If you can convince the voters, you will get an answer! So be convincing.

Comment: that's a fabricated question, why do you think that 1b) and 2b) are "ungrammtisch" (grammatically incorrect)? And what the heck has the inverse of the sentence to proof in example 3? **3b isn't used because it is incorrect, it sounds awful**, and you cannot lead from 1 and 2 towards 3, it is not related except the words

Comment: `... schon milliardenfach vorgekommen sind`: kein Mensch spricht so, niemals. Es sei denn, er möchte Max und Moritz von Wilhelm Busch imitieren, aber selbst da stimmt das Versmaß nicht - weder bei 1b, 2b noch 3b. Tut mir leid, ich sehe überhaupt keinen Unterschied, zwischen diesen 3 falschen Varianten.

Comment: @peterh  - Siehe hierzu z.B. https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wissen; "Typische Verbindungen", während hingegen 'Antwort' nicht vorkommt auf https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kennen. Oder auch https://www.dwds.de/wb/Antwort: "keine (rechte) Antwort wissen". Oder http://www.dict.cc/?s=know+the+answer, falls dir dict.cc nicht zu popelig ist. Was daraus folgt? Wenn du Suboptimalität diagnostizieren möchtest, dann nicht bei mir. :-))

Comment: @Stef - U.a. Duden: *hundertfach, tausendfach*, ... also auch: millionenfach, milliardenfach. Wenn dir "vorgekommen sind" nicht behagt, bitte schön: " generiert wurden". :-)) Ansonsten: Das Proleten-Komma klemmst du dir in Zukunft, okay? :-))

Comment: @multiplexetliber Ach wie ich doch all die Haarspalter und Kaffeebohnenzähler liebe - selbstredend ging es mir nicht um die konkrete Quantität und auch ein _generiert_ ändert nichts an der Aussage. Wenn etwas Falsches zigfach vorgekommen ist/generiert wurde, klingt das so, als ob es ein typische Fehler wäre. Das ist es in meinen Augen nicht. Ich habe täglich mit Ausländern unterschiedlicher deutscher Sprachkompetenz zu tun - da hört man schon mal _*weil ich nicht weiß die Antwort_, aber eben nie die genannten Formulierungen (weder 1b, 2b oder 3b).

Answer (score 1):

> dass parataktische Konstruktionen einfacher zu verarbeiten sind als hypotaktische

Ich finde das fast offensichtlich, warum 3b) hier nicht passt. Die Möglichkeit der einfacheren Verarbeitung geht hier verloren.
Die einfache Verarbeitung solcher Ausdrücke kommt ja daher, dass zwei selbständige Sätze einfacher verarbeitet werden, als ein Satz mit Nebensatz, wo dann die Wortstellung verändert wird.
Verbindet man nun zwei Sätze mit **"weil"**, dann wird in sehr einfacher Form eine Kausalität hergestellt. Das ist also die am schnellsten zu verarbeitende Konstruktion.

In 3b) wird dieses Prinzip aber zerstört. Das **"weil"** verbindet hier nichts mehr. Im Gegenteil werden wir so einen Beginn:

> Weil ich weiß die Antwort nicht,

immer als Antwort auf eine Frage erwarten.

Warum der zweite Teil uns aber komplett irritiert, ist der Satz als parataktische Konstruktionen beginnt, dann aber mit einer hypotaktischen Konstruktion endet. Der Satz beginnt also grammatisch falsch und endet mit der grammatisch richtigen, aber komplexeren Variante.

Comment: Das akzeptabel-bsp finde ich nicht akzeptabel, sehr konstruiert, das weil ist schlicht überflüssig und stört die syntax. Bemerkenswert auch, dass die Inversion mit "*darum*" nicht gleich funktioniert. Es wäre eher "...*ich sage darum nichts*" und würde quasi zu einer Präposition, dennoch als Konjunktion verstanden.

Comment: @vectory Du hast vollkommen recht. Ich glaube da ist letzten Endes nichts zu retten. Das *weil* a Anfang ist schon zu schräg für die beschriebene Situation. Außerdem war meine Lösung hypotaktisch, was ja meiner Argumentation widerspricht.

Answer (score 1):

Betrachten wir die zwei scheinbar sehr ähnlichen Sätze:

> [Wir haben drinnen gegessen], **denn** [draußen **war** es zu kalt].
>   [Wir haben drinnen gegessen, [**weil** es draußen zu kalt **war**]].

Man sieht sofort, daß die Position des finiten Verbs nicht die gleiche ist. Aber das ist nicht der einzige Unterschied. Der erste Satz ist eine Verbindung zweier *uneingebetteter* Sätze (Beiordnung): der denn-Satz ist nicht Teil von *Wir haben drinnen gegessen*. Im zweiten Beispiel ist der weil-Satz dagegen eingebettet. Die eckigen Klammern sollen die Verhältnisse verdeutlichen.

Ein Satz, der in einen anderen Satz eingebettet ist, kann, wie andere Satzglieder auch, im Vorfeld des einbettenden Satzes (des *Matrixsatzes*) stehen:

> [[Weil es draußen zu kalt war], haben wir drinnen gegessen].

Der Satz 3b) des Fragestellers ist also nicht ungrammatisch, weil das Verb an Position 2 steht, sondern weil ein beigeordneter (also nicht eingebetteter) Satz nicht im Vorfeld eines anderen Satzes stehen kann:

> *Denn es war draußen zu kalt, haben wir drinnen gegessen.

Noch ein weiteres Beispiel, das zeigt, daß beiordnendes *denn* und subordinierendes *weil* sich nicht nur in Bezug auf die Verbstellung unterscheiden:

> Sie mag Milch nicht nur, weil sie gesund ist, sondern auch, weil sie schmeckt.
>
> *Sie mag Milch nicht nur, denn sie ist gesund, sondern auch, denn sie schmeckt.

*Denn* läßt sich im Gegensatz zu *weil* nicht koordinieren.

Comment: Ich glaube rein intuitiv im letzen Bsp. sei ein Fehler, denn du trennst "auch weil". Zumindest wird "so dass" nicht durch Komma getrennt, so dass ich vermuten würde, das sei auch bei "auch weil" so, auch weil "sondern auch" allein keinen Nebensatz bildet. Oder zumindest, wenn das "auch" ein Nebensatz zu "Sie mag Milch" ist, dann passt "sondern" dort nicht rein.

Comment: Der *einbettende Satz* ist der Matrixsatz. Habe versucht, das etwas klarer zum Ausdruck zu bringen.

Answer (score 0):

2b) kann auch so interpretiert werden:

> Ich sage nichts, weil: Ich weiß die Antwort nicht.

Das ist kein besonders guter Stil, weswegen einem das im geschriebenen Deutsch kaum je begegnen wird. Aber es ist eine Erklärung, weshalb man 3b nicht zu hören bekommt, da dieser Satz nicht auf diese Weise interpretiert werden kann.