# "Welche Punkte sinnvoll wären zu ändern" oder "welche Punkte sinnvoll zu ändern wären"?

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order

Ich schreibe gerade eine Mail an einen Professor, in der ich folgenden Satz schreiben möchte:

> Sollten Sie Anregungen haben, welche Punkte am Thema sinnvoll **wären zu ändern**, bin ich natürlich offen für Vorschläge.

Ich bin mir allerdings gerade nicht sicher, ob "wären zu ändern" oder "zu ändern wären" die korrekte Reihenfolge ist. 
Natürlich könnte ich den Satz auch irgendwie umformulieren, aber irgendwie will ich jetzt auch wissen, was denn korrekt wäre :D

Comment: ohne "sinnvoll" klingt der Satz "Sollten Sie Anregungen haben, welche Punkte wären zu ändern" als wäre der zweite Teilsatz ein Hauptsatz. Wenn das der Fall ist, sollte er alleine stehen. Wenn der Satz eingebettet wird, ist eine andere Wortstellung notwendig, weil .. naja, [weil sonst der Satz klingt komisch](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49020/weil-ich-wei%c3%9f-die-antwort-nicht/49033#49033)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beide Varianten haben Nachteile:

> Sollten Sie Anregungen haben, welche Punkte am Thema sinnvoll zu ändern wären, bin ich natürlich offen für Vorschläge.

könnte so verstanden werden, als müssten *Punkte sinnvoll geändert* werden, dass *sinnvoll* sich also auf *Punkte* beziehen würde. Das könnte bedeuten, dass ein Punkt so geändert werden soll, dass er sinnvoll wird. Ausgedrückt werden soll aber, dass es sinnvoll sei, einen Punkt zu ändern.

Andererseits hat

> Sollten Sie Anregungen haben, welche Punkte am Thema sinnvoll wären zu ändern, bin ich natürlich offen für Vorschläge.

eine ungewöhnlich Satzstellung, über die man stolpert. Für mich ist diese Satzstellung ein Zeichen konzeptueller Mündlichkeit, und damit ein Stilniveau, das man in einer E-Mail an eine Autoritätsperson vielleicht nicht wählen möchte.

Eine Lösung bietet die Verwendung des markierten Adverbs:

> Sollten Sie Anregungen haben, welche Punkte am Thema sinnvollerweise zu ändern wären, bin ich natürlich offen für Vorschläge.

Damit wird restlos klar, dass *sinnvoll* sich auf *zu ändern wären* bezieht (und nicht auf *Punkte*), und die Satzstellung ist auch in Ordnung.

Answer (score 1):

Es geht **nur so, wie du geschrieben hast**.

> ... welche Punkte am Thema sinnvoll zu ändern wären

klingt komisch, so als ob es auch noch Punkte gäbe, die 'sinnlos' zu ändern wären (das sinnvoll bezieht sich hier auf *zu ändern*, es soll sich aber auf *wären* beziehen)

Ich würde das ***sinnvoll* ganz weglassen**: man darf ja annehmen, dass der Professor nur Änderungen vorschlagen wird, die auch sinnvoll sind. Insofern braucht man das bei der Frage nicht extra zu erwähnen. (dann geht natürlich nur *... welche Punkte am Thema zu ändern wären.*)

Comment: "das sinnvoll bezieht sich hier auf zu ändern, es soll sich aber auf wären beziehen" -das "sinnvoll" *soll* sich aber auf "zu ändern" beziehen. Wenn ein Punkt schon so passt, wie er derzeit formuliert ist, ist es ja auch sinnlos, ihn zu ändern.

Comment: @PixelMaster Naja, ein Punkt kann sinnvoll sein, dennoch kann es sinnvoll sein, ihn zu ändern. Um diesen Unterschied geht es hier.

Comment: Ich habe jetzt die Antwort von @jonathan.scholbach akzeptiert, da ich in der Frage explizit geschrieben hatte, dass es nicht um eine Umformulierung des Satzes geht, sondern darum, welche der beiden Varianten korrekt(er) wäre - und der Vorschlag, "sinnvoll" durch "sinnvollerweise" zu ersetzen, passt hierzu am besten. In der Mail werde ich dann allerdings "welche Punkte am Thema geändert werden sollten" schreiben, da der Vorschlag, "sinnvoll" wegzulassen durchaus berechtigt ist.

Comment: Ja, sinnvoll wegzulassen, ist natürlich auch eine gute Lösung.

Answer (score 0):

> Ich bin mir allerdings gerade nicht sicher, ob "wären zu ändern" oder
>   "zu ändern wären" die korrekte Reihenfolge ist.

"zu ändern wären" ist richtig!

Comment: Und warum? Für mich klingen nämlich auch beide Versionen möglich.

Comment: Bitte begründe auch, warum die eine Variante richtig ist und die andere nicht. Wie @Iris schreibt, klingen nämlich auch für mich beide Versionen möglich.

Comment: weil sie für mich nicht richtig klingen. ;)
was ist  sinnvoll? das" wäre" oder das "ändern"? sinnvoll bezieht sich auf das "ändern". Ich schreibe immer nur in konzeptueller Mündlichkeit ...

Answer (score 0):

Wenn ich es richtig verstehe, soll *sinnvoll* hier adverbial sein. Sonst müßte das Verb im Singular stehen. Die richtige Paraphrase ist also nicht A), mit der Infinitivkonstruktion als Subjekt und *sein* + Prädikativ, sondern B) mit *diese Punkte* als Subjekt und *sein* + zu-Infinitiv (dem sogenannten modalen Passiv).

> A) **Diese Punkte zu ändern** ist eine gute Idee.
>
> B) **Diese Punkte** sind (auf sinnvolle Weise) zu ändern.
> ~ "Diese Punkte müssen/können (auf sinnvolle Weise) geändert werden."

Im Fall B) ist die Verbindung von *sein* und zu-Infinitiv nicht anders als die von *haben* und Partizip: Sie bilden im Nebensatz einen Verbalkomplex, in dem das abhängige Verb zuerst steht.

> B') ob diese Punkte (auf sinnvolle Weise) **zu ändern sind**
> B'') welche Punkte (auf sinnvolle Weise) **zu ändern sind**
>
> welche Punkte am Thema (auf sinnvolle Weise) **zu ändern wären**

Dagegen paßt der folgende Satz nur zu A). Die Infinitivkonstruktion ist dann entweder aufgespalten oder steht als Ganzes am Anfang des Relativsatzes.

> A') **welche Punkte** (es) eine gute Idee ist **zu ändern**
> A'') **welche Punkte zu ändern** eine gute Idee ist

Ich habe in den Beispielen *sinnvoll* durch *auf sinnvolle Weise* bzw. *eine gute Idee* ersetzt. So wird zum einen der Unterschied zwischen den Konstruktionen A) und B) deutlicher; zum anderen finde ich *sinnvoll* im modalen Passiv eher schlecht.

> ? Diese Punkte sind sinnvoll zu ändern.
> ~ "Diese Punkte müssen/können sinnvoll geändert werden."

Comment: Die Analyse ist super, aber ich glaube, der Beitrag ist noch nicht allgemein verständlich.

Comment: Wo hapert es denn?

Comment: Naja, zum Beispiel wäre ein expliziter Schluss hilfreich, welcher der beiden in Rede stehenden Sätze denn nun als richtig aus der Analyse folgt.

Comment: @David, der abschließenden Bemerkung gegen "*sinnvoll zu ändern*" wegen würde sich "*welche Punkte am Thema zu ändern sinnvoll wäre -- Diese Punkte zu ändern wäre sinnvoll*" entsprechend deinem Bsp. A doch als sinnvoll herausstellen.