# Hauptsatz nach dem/im Nebensatz

Tags: word-order

Ist die Wortreihenfolge hier richtig und ist sie das, was ein Muttersprachler aussuchen würde?

> Ich esse Karotten, weil ich glaube, sie sind gesund.

Ich frage mich gerade, ob das Wort "weil", das einen Nebensatz anfängt, den Rest des Satzes so betrifft, dass die Reihenfolge eigentlich "sie gesund sind" sein sollte. Ich vermute nicht, aber bin nicht sicher. Ich denke jedenfalls, man könnte auch sagen: "Ich esse Karotten, weil, glaube ich, sie gesund sind." Würde das (oder auch etwas anderes) natürlicher klingen?

Comment: Verwandte [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/6339/1696).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Für mich wäre die "natürlichste" Form:

> Ich esse Karotten, weil ich glaube, dass sie gesund sind.

Dein Beispiel ist kaum weniger natürlich:

> Ich esse Karotten, weil ich glaube, sie sind gesund.

Die Reihenfolge ist richtig so, wenn du es ohne "dass" schreibst. Man nennt das dann einen *abhängigen Hauptsatz*:

> Ich glaube, ich spinne!
> Sie sagt, sie kennt ihn nicht.
> Er behauptet, Kartoffeln sind gesund, wenn man sie nicht gerade als Pommes isst.

Deine alternative Version ist nicht falsch, der Einschub "glaube ich" klingt nur etwas unnatürlich an der Stelle. Er würde sehr viel besser  nach dem Subjekt des Weil-Nebensatzes kommen:

> Ich esse Karotten, weil sie, glaube ich, gesund sind.